# Checkbox value array

Tags: php

I am trying to get the values of selected check boxes within a form however I need to store an array within the value tag which holds an ID and the Day.

Something like so:

```
echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[ind]" id="'.$ind['ID'].'" value="'.$valueArr[$ind['ID']]['Fri'].'">Friday</label>';

echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[grp]" id="'.$ind['ID'].'" value="'.$valueArr[$ind['ID']]['Sat'].'">Sat</label>';


if (isset($_POST['check_list'])){
    $indchks = $_POST['check_list']['ind'];
    $grpchks = $_POST['check_list']['grp'];

    $G = count($grpchks);
    $N = count($indchks);

    for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++){
        //Need to somehow delve into the value array?
        //insertIndBooking($talent_id, $id, $day);
    }
```

These values will later have to be read and posted to a DB. My problem being, I am not so certain what I am doing is correct or how I am going to read this array.

Any and all help is gratefully received

Kind Regards,

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything. I am pretty sure `$valueArr[$ind['ID']]['Fri']` is wrong

Comment: Have you looked at what gets placed on the pace using `view page source` in your browser

Comment: If you are not sure what your $_POST array looks like add a `print_r($_POST);` to your code and you will see it shown to you

Comment: I am getting `Notice: Undefined index: grp Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 ` as well as the many `Notice: Undefined variable: valueArr ` ...

Comment: Well then look at each error, **each gives you a line number** and fix whatever is wrong

Comment: I am getting Array ( [check_list] => Array ( [ind] => ) therefore those arrays in the values are not quite what they should.

Comment: Count the opening and closing brackets on this `$valueArr[$ind['ID']]['Fri']` they do not match

Comment: So your first comment on the $ValueArr being wrong was spot on.